# What's wrong with Deserialize part of code

Tags: c#

Code:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        formatter.Serialize(m, list);
        m.Position = 0;
        return Convert.ToBase64String(m.ToArray());
    } 

}

public static T Deserialize<T>(string listData)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        return (IEnumerable<T>)formatter.Deserialize(m); //Problem is here
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' to 'T'. An
explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: sorry if answer was trivial :(

Comment: Wrong return type, return IEnumerable<T>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the return type from `T` to `IEnumerable<T>`.  You also need to fill the memory stream with the string, for instance:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Deserialize<T>(string listData)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(listData)))
    {
        return (IEnumerable<T>)formatter.Deserialize(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error with the code above:   +  $exception {"The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 41-41-45-41-41-41-44-2F-2F-2F-2F-2F-41-51-41-41-41 ..."} System.Exception {System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException}

Comment: @rod Oops!  I didn't pay attention to how you were encoding the string in your Serialize method.  I fixed it so it now uses base64 encoding instead of UTF8.

Answer (score 3):

As the message clearly says, you can't return an `IEnumerable<T>` from a method declared as returning `T`.

Comment: Not that it's gonna fix the program - for one, the listData parameter is not used anywhere